# IntelliJ IDEA. Compound doesn't work as 'Before launch' task

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

IntelliJ IDEA and other idea-based IDEs have Run/Debug Configurations that help users to create templates of frequently used tasks. One of the possible run configurations is [Compound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddlA3.png), which can include multiple run configurations/tasks and run them in parallel.

To mix the execution order IDEA also has [Before launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Qla.png) option that allows us to define tasks or other run configurations that should run before the given task.
The problem is Compound works great when not included in any execution queue. When I try to define compound as the before launch task, the compound tasks get executed, but the run configuration where I have defined before launch option - not.

**Here is a reproducible example.**

1. Create 3 Shell Script run configurations: script_1, script_2 & script_3.
2. Each script should log its name into the console using provided script text like is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg6k1.png).
3. Combine script_1 & script_2 into the new Compound Run Configuration like is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efrl7.png).
4. Add the created compound to the Before Launch tasks of script_3.

**Expected Result**: script_1 & script_2 are executed in parallel and after they're done IDEA starts execution of the script_3.

**Actual result**: script_1 & script_2 are executed in paralel and after they're done ***nothing*** happens.

I haven't found any useful information about how exactly compound works along with other run configurations in the execution queue, but I also have tried the Multirun plugin as a workaround. This plugin's documentation states that it should be perfect to use it instead of compounds in this particular situation, however, developers also state that official functionality like Compound is still preferable. I've tried case [Runs tasks A, B before task C](https://github.com/rkhmelyuk/multirun/wiki/How-to-run-configurations-with-Multirun) in many different combinations and it doesn't even work in a plugin, not even talking about official compounds. Anything special in IDEA logs with both compounds and the Multirun plugin.

Question: am I doing something wrong? Or maybe it's an IDEA bug that should be reported?

Anyway, if compounds shouldn't work like this, why IDEA displays them in Before Launch tasks options? Please tell me what you think.

**Tested on** IDEA versions 2021.2.3 & 2020.3.4

Comment: Seems to be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. Please submit at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: Reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-300384/

Comment: looks like they fixed it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-320876 - haven't tested yet on new versions